# Usage of "as necessary"

Tags: word-usage

I wrote :

> This program uses the *master* ruleset, which contains some basic and general rules. Some of these rules will be presented **later as necessary**.

I used "as necessary" to say when it was necessary we may discuss some of the rules. Did I used it correctly?  Is it normal to combine it with "later"?

Comment: I don't have a problem with the phrase, but it makes me wonder how later this would be, like later in this document?, or maybe later next year? Logically, I would assume that it's later in this document, but seeing "when it was necessary we may discuss some of the rules", I'm not so sure. How could the writer(s) not know if they have or have not discussed what rules? (Of course, when we're writing our documents, it's always a work in progress, but from the reader's point of view, the document is finished.)

Comment: You should use the phrase "as necessary" only as necessary. Here it is not necessary.  *The author is assumed to have completed the book or the text*, and thus to know whether or not the rules have been presented later.  **Later** is fine. It is understood to mean "below in this text".  So one could write "Some of these rules **are** discussed below."

Comment: @DamkerngT. in the current document.

Comment: as necessary = as the need *may* arise. Take one or two tablets to control pain, as necessary.

Comment: @TRomano In my article it become necessary when I bring an example code which is dependent to some rules of the *master* ruleset. In that case I provide the related rules. is it *as necessary*?

Comment: @Ahmad: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Some of these rules will be presented later as necessary."
>
> I used "as necessary" to say when it **was** necessary we **may discuss** some
>   of the rules. But can I still combine it with "later"? Is it natural?

[my emphasis]

The snippet of text I've quoted from your question reveals the problem. I've highlighted your *confusion of tenses*.

With future-looking tenses, **as necessary** means "as the need *may* arise", whereas with past-looking tenses, **as necessary** means "as the need did arise".

> I will take one or two tablets to control pain, as necessary.
>
> I took one or two tablets to control pain, as necessary.

In your sentence

"Some of these rules **will be presented** later as necessary."

you're using a future tense, which, in context, makes the sentence incongruous, because it would mean

**Some of these rules will be presented later (in this book) if the need should arise.**

As an author you are expected to know whether the need has arisen. The book is not a mystery unfolding before you, but a composition you have created and then *edited afterwards*.

Comment: I see, you mean when someone says "as necessary", he himself doesn't know if it will become necessary or not? I also can't talk about *past*. Then you say *as necessary* has not much usage in a book or article? I also commented that we will present them when we bring a relevant example. Which phrase can be used for such case?

Comment: @Ahmad. Correct. As in the example with the pain tablets, we don't know whether one or two tablets will be required to still the pain, or if there will be pain severe enough to warrant taking even a single pill. As always, don't paint yourself into a corner; there is always more than one way to say something. For example, you can say *Later in the book we will examine (or present) sample code in which some of these master rules are used*.

Comment: Thank you, I have another question, do "where necessary" and "when necessary" have the same implication?

Comment: Yes, they do. The meaning will be 'when|where the need may arise' when used with future-looking tenses and 'when|where the need did arise' when used with past-looking tenses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning  is clearer if you  use the expression: 
***if need be***: 
​

> - if it is necessary:
>     *If need be, we can take two cars*

Cambridge Dictionary

- Some of the rules can be presented later  if need be.